# Choosing $x$ to minimize norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be a symmetric, positive-definite $M \times M$-matrix and
$||p||_V = \sqrt{p^{T}Vp}$ for every $p \in R^N$.

What's the optimal algorithm for choosing $x \in R^N$ to minimize $||b - Ax||_V$, where $b \in R^M$, matrix $A$ size is $M \times N$ with $M \ge N$ and $\mathrm{rank}(A) = N$?

I only have an idea for a solution hen $V$ is the identity matrix, but not for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\|b-Ax\|_V=\|V^{1/2}b-V^{1/2}Ax\|_2$, this is just an ordinary least square problem and the optimal solution is given by $x=(V^{1/2}A)^+V^{1/2}b$, where $X^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of a matrix $X$.

In your case, as $A$ has full column rank, we have
$$
x=(V^{1/2}A)^+V^{1/2}b
=\left[(V^{1/2}A)^T(V^{1/2}A)\right]^{-1}(V^{1/2}A)^TV^{1/2}b
=(A^TVA)^{-1}A^TVb.
$$